# REST API in PHP output to JSON file extension

Tags: php, json, api, file, rest

So I want to write a REST API in PHP for JSON for consumption on the iPhone, but also a lot of websites and devices.  I have the below code, when accessed via a GET statement, returns a file like:

1mdi2o3.part

How do I return something like:  users.json

```
$db->setQuery( "SELECT * FROM users");
$db->query() or die($queryError);
$numRows = $db->getNumRows();
$row = $db->loadObjectList();

// PRINT JSON FILE
header("Content-type: application/json");

for($i = 0 ; $i < $numRows; $i++){
$json_output[$i] = $row[$i];
}

$MYjson_output = json_encode($json_output);

echo $MYjson_output;
```

Comment: Can you show a live example? The code looks ok.

Answer (score 10):

Not entirely such what your goal is but here are 3-4 solutions that might work:

### Common Solutions

#### Rewrite

This is probaly the most conventional way of getting clean URIs for your API. If you want the user part of user.json to be dynamic, you can use mod_rewrite (again assuming Apache) to rewrite your URLs to a php handler script.  If you are going the conventional RESTful style URL route, you will probably want to use this anyway to achieve clean `/` separated URLs.

```
# For grabbing all users
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^users\.json rest.php [L]

# For grabbing one particular user
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)\.json rest.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Where rest.php is your PHP handler script.

#### URL Rewriting without mod-rewrite

If you don't want to use mod_rewrite, you can also do something like

```
example.com/rest.php/users.json
example.com/rest.php/user-id.json
```

or even

```
example.com/rest.php/user-id
example.com/rest.php/user/user-id
```

Where rest.php is your PHP handler script.  You can grab the `user-id` from the URL (or URI if we're talking RESTful terms) using the `$_SERVER` global with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

### Other solutions

#### Changing download name via Content-Disposition:

I believe you want to add the [Content-Disposition](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2183) header...

```
<?php
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="users.json"');
?>
```

This will force the file to be downloaded as user.json.  This usually isn't the behavior expected for a REST API, but from the way your question was worded, I figured I'd throw it out there.

#### AddHandler (or AddType)

Assuming you're running an Apache server, you can also just use `AddHandler` directive to make `.json` extension files be treated like they are php.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .json
```

*Warning:  Other plain .json files will be treated as PHP so you'd probably want to set this in a .htaccess file in the directory with the PHP script.  This would work fine for this one URI but not ideal if you were exposing many URIs*

Answer (score -2):

Welcome to SO.  Have you considered using the [Zend framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.rest.server.html) for this application?  I've [written about this topic before](http://ajcoon.blogspot.com/2009/09/rest-services-supporting-xml-and-json.html), and if you do use Zend I could probably be of additional help.  It would certainly help get you past the basics.

HTH,

-aj

Comment: Sorry, but "use Zend" seems like a bit of overkill for solving a simple problem like this...

Comment: @Wim, the OP appears to be developing his own REST server and I was merely pointing out an alternative to reinventing the wheel.  BTW, see my comment on *your* answer.

Comment: You're right, it can be useful for him. But if it can be solved in 10 lines, I'm always hesitant to add in some 10K lines of framework first ;-)

Answer (score -2):

The problem is this line:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

I know this looks like the right way to do (after all, `application/json` *is* the official MIME type for JSON content), but it causes most browsers to present you with a file download dialog, when you just want to see the text. You can use the `text/plain` encoding to avoid this. Note that your AJAX/iPhone/... app probably doesn't care about the content type, so your API will work in both cases.

Also see [this blog post](http://simonwillison.net/2009/Feb/6/json/) which provides some more context.

Comment: @Wim, wouldn't it be text/json ?

Comment: I was just quoting the OP here. `application/json` is the official one though I think. Maybe with `text/json` you could fool the browser into displaying it as plain text, but in that case `text/plain` would be equivalent I guess.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type `application/json` is the best option.

Comment: Also, I use `text/json` and don't have a problem on IE6-8, FF3 and Chrome, but I don't know about WebKit stuff like the iPhone.

Comment: You should really use the proper MIME type and text/plain is not it. I use Firebug in Firefox to test my JSON web services and use console.log to show me the JSON data. It is a great way to verify it is working properly. You will find that some systems want to the proper MIME type or they will reject the data.