# Create json data file with extension '.json'

Tags: javascript, php, json

I want to fetch latest Drupal 7 posts in json format with the file extension of '.json'

I have tried multiple methods to GET data in JSON format using PHP but doing so keeps the file name as .php, I am unable to create the '.json' file.

**How to create dynamic JSON file like this?:** http://json-schema.org/example/calendar.json

Can someone please share some inputs or help with some useful resource which I can refer to in order to achieve this.

**DUPLICATE - This may be a duplicate question but there is no answer available for this. The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169683/rest-api-in-php-output-to-json-file-extension) provided by '[Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin)' does not have an accepted answer and also it does not have the answer to my question.**

Comment: You don't need it to have a `.json` extension to work. A `.php` extension (or no extension!) can output JSON just fine, you'll just want to send the proper `Content-Type: application/json` header.

Comment: Agreed, but I would like to know how to generate a '.json' extension. Could you please help with that?

Comment: Is this question about creating the JSON output,  or the file ending?

Comment: If you want the later,  the duplicate answer contains the solution - even  if not accepted